# What is the best data model for timeseries in Cassandra when *fast sequential reads* are required

Tags: cassandra, time-series

I want to store streaming financial data into Cassandra and read it back fast. I will have up to 20000 instruments ("tickers") each containing up to 3 million 1-minute data points. I have to be able to *read* large ranges of each of these series as speedily as possible (indeed it is the reason I have moved to a columnar-type database as MongoDB was suffocating on this use case). Sometimes I'll have to read the whole series. Sometimes I'll need less but typically the most recent data first. I also want to keep things really simple.

Is this model, which I picked up in a Datastax [tutorial](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling), the most effective? Not everyone seems to agree.

```
CREATE TABLE minutedata (
  ticker text,
  time timestamp,
  value float,
  PRIMARY KEY (ticker, time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

I like this because there are up to 20 000 tickers so the partitioning should be efficient, and there are only up to 3 million minutes in a row, and Cassandra can handle up to 2 billion. Also with the time descending order I get most recent data when using a limit on the query.

However, the book Cassandra High Availability by Robbie Strickland mentions the above as an *anti-pattern* (using sensor-data analogy), and I quote the problems he cites from page 144:

- Data will be collected for a given sensor indefinitely, and in many
  cases at a very high frequency
- With sensorID as the partition key, the row will grow by two
  columns for every reading (one marker and one reading).

I understand point one would be a problem but it's not in my case due to the 3 million data point limit. But point 2 is interesting. What are these "markers" between each reading? I clearly want to avoid anything that breaks contiguous data storage.

If point 2 is a problem, what is a better way to model timeseries so that they can efficiently be read in large ranges, fast? I'm not particularly keen to break the timeseries into smaller sub-periods.

Comment: Is HBase-based system allowed to be a contender? 3 mln samples per ticker is 30 years worth of data assuming regular trading hours, correct?

Comment: @Sergei Rodionov: No. Some tickers such as the major FX markets trade 24 hours. In these cases 3 million gets us to Jan 2000. The majority of my series don't get anywhere near 3 million points (mean is about 800k). Still we're talking billions of datapoints. Ideally for a single ticker I'd like 1 million in less than 5 seconds. Getting 25 seconds with my 3-node 16gb/SSD test cluster on Cassandra. Yes Hbase is entirely able to be a contender. I didn't like the idea of setting up zookeeper, and other dependencies, so went with Cassandra but if you tell me that Hbase is better, I am listening....

Comment: I'll bite the bullet and say that HBase setup is indeed more abstruse. Full disclosure too: I work for the company whose product I'm about to recommend. http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/ - CE edition is free. It installs the HBase stack in pseudo-cluster mode on one machine. 20K tickers at 5/sec = 100K/sec. It should be able to ingest this rate on one well-endowed node, but I'd like to see how much mileage can be squeezed out from minutely data.

Comment: Okay my ingest rate is not an issue. Ingesting 20k points per minute is small for most NoSQL DBs. My main problem is getting data back out really fast for single tickers. IE: 1 million reads from one ticker in less than 5 seconds. I need something that will basically get close to the speed of flat binary files. I'll take a look at axibase.

Comment: I'll check on our test instances what's the read time for 1M rows: same ticker same metric, e.g. price. What's the total number of rows you have in Cassandra installation that produces 5 second response?

Comment: I was able to download 1M minutely samples in json format in 8 seconds from db to file via curl, timing based on "Time spent" column in curl output. 2 seconds if I query for the same 1M raw sample count for monthly or for daily averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query pattern was to find a few rows for a ticker using a range query, then I would say having all the data for a ticker in one partition would be a good approach since Cassandra is optimized to access partitions efficiently.

But if everything is in one one partition, then that means the query is happening on only one node. Since you say you often want to read large ranges of rows, then you may want more parallelism.

If you split that same data across many nodes and read it in parallel, you may be able to get better performance.  For example, if you partitioned your data by ticker and by year, and you had ten nodes, you could theoretically issue ten async queries and have each year queried in parallel.

Now 3 million rows is a lot, but not really *that* big, so you'd probably have to run some tests to see which approach was actually faster for your situation.

If you're doing more than just retrieving all these rows and are doing some kind of analytics on them, then parallelism will become more attractive and you might want to look into pairing Cassandra with Spark so that the data and be read and processed in parallel on many nodes.

Comment: thanks yes I may try the 1-year partitioning, though I would have preferred to keep things simpler, but it's worth it if I get say 2-3x speed up or more. I will try it and feedback. Separately would you be able to comment on this issue of "markers"? When I chose Cassandra I was under the impression that in a data model such as that which I have described above, all the datapoints for a ticker would be stored *contiguously* on disk for fastest possible linear access. Is this correct? Am I getting a pure sequential read? Or are there even better ways to maximize linear read speed in Cassandra?

Comment: When a memtable fills up and is flushed to disk as an SSTable, the data is stored in sorted order by the the clustering columns, so that data is contiguous.  Over time you may have multiple SSTables on disk and if the data is changing over time, then a row may appear in multiple SSTables requiring several reads.  When you get enough SSTables, they will be compacted and merged.  As long as you are doing your range queries using a clustering column then your reads will be mostly sequential reads and fairly fast.  The only way to go faster is with more parallelism by engaging multiple nodes.